# getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

MainActivity.kt :
https://gist.github.com/0xN1nja/537ec6ad7d00c2284d7788f92de0a600

Model :
[image]

Error :

```
    Process: com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite, PID: 12674
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.SupportPreconditions.checkArgument(SupportPreconditions.java:104)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:309)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:328)
        at com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:40)
        at com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$hODd9Y72uZ7cKE8WuAJp-ZdH6JA(MainActivity.kt)
        at com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10565)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
2022-07-31 14:16:50.267 12674-12674/com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12674 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your byte buffer should match to your Machine Learning models. for example you have img size param in your machine learning for 224x224, then your buffer file from client side also must have 224x224.

Comment: how to resize then?

Comment: I take this from your code

 var resized:Bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,50,50,false),

your bitmap size is 50x50. It must be have same size with your ML model param